# Python - Remove whitespace from the end of each line of output

Tags: python, whitespace

```
def print_gameboard(gamestate):
    for row in gamestate._gameboard:
        for column in row:
            if column == gamestate._NONE:
                print('.', end = ' ')
            else:
                print(column, end = ' ')
        print()
```

My function is outputting:
. . . .(whitespace)
. . . .(whitespace)
. . . .(whitespace)
. . . .(whitespace)

I can't figure out how to remove the whitespace from the end only of each line. I've tried using `.rstrip()` but I need spaces in between each '.' (dot) but I can't have whitespace at the very end of each output line.

Comment: `rstrip('\n').rstrip()` should work. Just remember to put line breaks back in.

Comment: using strip or rstrip does not remove whitespace between the characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple change,

```
def print_gameboard(gamestate):
    for row in gamestate._gameboard:
        rowList = []
        for column in row:            
            if column == gamestate._NONE:
                rowList.append('.')                
            else:
                rowList.append(column)
        str=' '.join(rowList)
        print str.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of messing around with `end`, it may be easier to just join the row while applying a conditional statement and then print it:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join('.' if col == gamestate._NONE else col for col in row) for row in gamestate._gameboard)
```

Comment: It is surely a good one-line solution, but it also makes code more complicated. I think there is no need to merge them into one line.